# Java Function returning null

Tags: java, ejb, oracle-adf

I'm trying to develop a function that return a string if the result is successful or not

here is my function :

```
 public String addAssistanceRecord(Date dateCreation, BigDecimal dureeAssistance, String etatAssistance,
                  String idAssistance, String ingAff, String ouvertPar, String sujetAss, String dep,String client,String idContrat) {


        Assistance assistance = new Assistance();
        assistance.setClient(client);
        assistance.setDateCreation(dateCreation);
        assistance.setDep(dep);
        assistance.setDureeAssistance(dureeAssistance);
        assistance.setIngAff(ingAff);
        assistance.setOuvertPar(ouvertPar);
        assistance.setSujetAss(sujetAss);
        assistance.setIdAssistance(idAssistance);
        assistance.setEtatAssistance(etatAssistance);


        //setting the contratid explicitly
          Contrat contrat = new Contrat();
             contrat.setIdContrat(idContrat);
                 assistance.setContrat(contrat);

       //persist the assistance object data to ASS table


                      Contrat con1 =assistance.getContrat();
                      String idCon= con1.getIdContrat();
                    //  System.out.println("id contrat "+ idCon);


     Query query =
         em.createQuery("SELECT a from Contrat a where a.idContrat =:id");

     query.setParameter("id", idCon);
     Contrat con2 = (Contrat) query.getSingleResult();
     em.persist(assistance);

    // System.out.println("id contrat 2 "+ con2.getIdContrat());
     //System.out.println("nb jr contrat 2 "+ con2.getNbJours());

     BigDecimal nbJours = con2.getNbJours();
     BigDecimal sldj =con2.getSoldeJours();
     int monSolde;
     if(sldj==null){

         monSolde =0;
     }
     else {
              monSolde=(con2.getSoldeJours()).intValueExact(); 
         }


       int monAssistance= (assistance.getDureeAssistance()).intValueExact();
       System.out.println("mon Solde est "+monSolde);
     System.out.println("ma durée est "+monAssistance);  

     if((monSolde - monAssistance > 0) ){
             if(monSolde==0){
         nbJours = nbJours.subtract(assistance.getDureeAssistance());

          con2.setSoldeJours(nbJours);
                 em.merge(con2);
               return "success";

     }
             else{
             nbJours = sldj.subtract(assistance.getDureeAssistance());

              con2.setSoldeJours(nbJours);
                     em.merge(con2);
               return "success";

     }



     }
     else {
             return "daddaaa";
         }

 }
```

here the condition where i compare **((monSolde - monAssistance > 0) )**

and here my function in the my managed bean

```
public String Verification() {
        oracle.binding.BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("addAssistanceRecord");
       Object result = operationBinding.getResult();
      System.out.println("## Result = " + result);
         if (result == "success") {
            String messageText = "Votre Consommation du contrat est ajouté avec succès";
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(messageText);


            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, fm);
            return null;

        } 
        else 
        {
            String messageText = "Impossible d'ajouter cette consommation: la durée d'assistance est inférieure  a celle du contrat choisi";
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(messageText);


            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, fm);
            return null;

        }


    }
```

when i excute my function it do correctly all the work but the function (Verification)always return null

Comment: Not only this is a duplicate, but you have `if (something) { .. return null; } else { return null; }`. Think about why your method returns `null` then. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have always `null` because you have always `return null;`.Try to use:

```
   `retrun result;` instead of `return null;` .
```

Try to replace this:

```
  if (result == "success") {
```

With using `equals` instead of `==`:

```
 if ("success".equals(result)) {
```

Comment: thank you for help, i just follow your reponse and it's always returning null, can you check the first methode for me please?!!

Comment: @user3419507 in the first method where's:  em

Comment: it's declared in the top of the class

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two Strings you need to use the `equals()` function and not the `==` operator because the `==` check if the two objects are pointing to the same place in memory, the `equals()` function instead is overridable and when comparing two strings check if the values are the same.